# can we use condition in useReducers methods

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{useReducer} from 'react'

const initialState = {
   first : 0
}

const reducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
      case 'inc':
        return { first : state.firstc + 1}
      case 'dec' :
        if(initialState > 0){
          return  { first : state.firstc - 1}
        }else{
           return initialState

      case 'reset':
        return initialState
    }
}

export default function App() {

  const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (

    <div>
      
      <div>count-{count.first}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type : 'inc'})} >inc</button>

    
      <button onClick={ () => dispatch({type:'dec' })}>dec</button> 
      

      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type:'reset'})}>reset</button>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am learning useReducer hooks and stuck here !!
here increment and reset buttons works perfectly but when i click to decrement button every times it return me the value of initialState itself

Comment: `firstc` looks like a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialState` is an object, so it can't be compared to a number, the `initialState > 0` condition is always false.

You want to compare to the current `state.first` value.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'inc':
      return {
        first: state.first + 1
      };

    case 'dec':
      if (state.first > 0) {
        return {
          first: state.first - 1
        }
      } else {
        return initialState;
      }

    case 'reset':
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

I typically prefer to use a bounding function.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'inc':
      return {
        first: state.first + 1
      };

    case 'dec':
      return {
        first: Math.max(0, state.first - 1),
      };

    case 'reset':
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   case 'dec' :
        if(state.first > 0){
          return  { first : state.first - 1}
        }else{
           return initialState
```

error is with the condition check. And for your question "yes" you can acutally have a condition inside the useReducer reduce method. It behaves like a normal function